# Don't exist $k<5^{n}-5^{n-1}$ that $5^{n}\mid 2^{k}-1$

Tags: contest-math, divisibility, totient-function

I want to prove that doesn't exist $k<5^{n}-5^{n-1}$ where $5^{n}\mid 2^{k}-1$.

I know that the Euler-Fermat Theorem says
\begin{equation}
2^{\phi(5^{n})}\equiv 1 \mod 5^{n}
\end{equation}
where $\phi(5^{n})=5^{n}-5^{n-1}$. I wonder if this is the minimum exponent that accomplish this equation. If $k$ not divide $\phi(5^n)$ and $k$ is the least, is evident. But what occur if $k\mid \phi(5^n)$? I'm stuck.

Comment: Primitive roots mod prime powers are well understood, see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n)

Comment: lulu, very interesting. I'll see that.

Comment: Here's an article where they work out and prove a similar example but with $3$ instead of $5$, https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/#solution-to-problem-2

Comment: Thank you! That solves the question.